# Receiving 'Completed 500 Internal Service Error'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Twilio integration, and when I receive a text from a phone number, I want to look up that phone number in the `Users` table in my database to see if they exist, then do some action.

Here are the parameters I'm seeing in the console which I'm getting from the POST call from Twilio (I removed sensitive or irrelevant ones):

```
Parameters: {"SmsStatus"=>"received", "Body"=>"Blah blah blah", "From"=>"+15555555555"}
```

And here is the controller method which is getting hit. After I get the phone number, I am trying to (1) create a user instance, (2) extract any URL I'm receiving in the body of the text, and (3) create a new `link` entry in the DB.

```
    def incoming_text
        user = User.where(phone: params[:From])
        if user.present?
            url = URI.extract(params[:Body])
            if url.present?
                @link = Link.new(user_id: user[:id], link: url) #Row 27
                ...
            end
        end
    end
```

Here is the schema for my `users` table:

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "phone"
    t.boolean "confirmed"
  end

  create_table "links", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "link"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_links_on_user_id"
  end
```

Here are the logs. I have also included a TypeError I am getting for Row 26.

```
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."phone" = ?  [["phone", "+15555555555"]]
#<User:0x00007efcedb05400>
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)

TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:27:in `incoming_text'
```

Comment: What's the class of `user`? (see `user.class`)

Comment: @SebastianPalma When I put  `user.class` it says `User::ActiveRecord_Relation`. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Sure, you've assigned user to a collection of users, that's the problem. To access a user id, you need to have a single user, what you have now are many users, so, that's the problem.

Comment: You should use `User.find_by(phone: params[:From])` instead `where`, `find_by` will return a single object, the first if the query returns results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

Ok now it's clear.

The problem is you're trying to access [:id] from a collection of Users returned by User.where, it'll be possible only on a single User object.

So you need to change your logic to iterate over that collection:

```
users = User.where(phone: params[:From])
users.each do |user|
  # then you can access user.id here
end
```

Or just take the first from that list with `.first`

```
user = User.where(phone: params[:From]).first
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, give me valid example of "Body", because then it might be how you're trying to Uri.extract on it.

Comment: Still not working:
`User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."phone" = ?  [["phone", "+15555555555"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms) TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer): app/controllers/users_controller.rb:27:in incoming_text `

Here's a body example:
`Parameters: {"SmsStatus"=>"received", "Body"=>"https://reuters.com",  "From"=>"+15555555555"}`

Comment: `params` values are converted to string in Rails 5. And they're accessible in both ways, since the use of `with_indifferent_access` on them.

Comment: @SebastianPalma yeah but we don't know which version he's using and this question was completely different before. The updated answer might do the job

Comment: @SebastianPalma Apologies for modifying the question before. I noticed I provided the wrong lines. As for changing `user[:id]` to `user.id`, I'm now getting the following `NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fcd2c7c6888>`

Comment: If `user` is an `ApplicationRecord(abstract)` inherited object, then you can access to its methods with `[method_name]` or `.method_name`, so that's probably not the problem.

Comment: @SebastianPalma you're right! Thanks for the correction.